# How do I add dates for the beginning and end of the week in one cell

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-dates, google-sheets-cell-format

I know very little about Google Sheets and all I want to do is create a cell that will display the beginning and end of the week, like this: 7/22-7/28.

I'd like to be able to drag this across multiple cells and have it be the next week's dates. Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 3):

A1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN("-",TEXT({"7/22","7/28"}+(COLUMN(A1)-1)*7,"M/DD")))
```

Drag to right.

- Two dates are initialized and a column number*7 is added per each column.
- TEXT  to format dates " m/dd"
- JOIN the 2 dates by `-`

Answer (score 1):

with one more column:

- **cell A1: `=TEXT(DATE(2018,7,15)+B1,"m/d")&"-"&TEXT(DATE(2018,7,21)+B1,"m/d")`**
- **cell B1: `7`**
- **cell B2: `=B1+7`**

and then drag down **A1** and **B2**

**[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aQmqxQ55pqX6_PvUNcGuWpfMajpSii8AhBRLOsGuq9g/edit#gid=0)**

[image]